# I need to get text from textfield or textview with linebreak

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I need to get text from user input textfield or textview.
I made rect and draw text into the rect.
code is below.

```
CGRect a = CGRectMake(0,500,2400,100);
[textfield.text drawInRect:a 
                  withFont:font 
                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
                  alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

the problem is if user input too long text, [drawInRect] just draws like ... or cut the middle of sentance.
I want make double line if user input long sentance, but linebreakmode seems like ignores following text if long. What do I have to do to get full text?

Comment: do you mean you want the see whole text in text field, like multiple lines?

Comment: not in the textfield. I make image file with text. If the sentence is out of rect, I want to draw the text next line in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
 CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(textfield.frame.size.width, 1000); //here 1000 for maximum height u can increase this if u want
 CGSize strSize = [textfield.text sizeWithFont:textfield.font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
 CGRect newframe = CGRectMake(0, 0, strSize.width, strSize.height);
 [textfield.text drawInRect:newframe 
                  withFont:textfield.font 
             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
                 alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```